Copal #0 lens aperture setting
I just bought a used Fujifilm GX617 from a big name camera store in NYC (B..), with a 180mm lens, and rated 9/10 by their ratings.  The lens is nominally f/6.7 to f/45, and here is where it gets weird for me.  The f-stop selection pointer moves past the f/45 indicator end by a significant amount, and there is a an obvious difference in aperture between the indicated f/45 and where the pointer actually ends.  Here are the f/6.7, nominal f/45 and  f/?? examples



This is my first big boy camera that uses a Copal lens, so this situation has me wondering what did I just buy.  The aperture selection is smooth all the way though, and the shutter speed, and overall shutter/aperture operation seems reasonable as well.  So my question are legion:

Should the selector typically be able to go past the f/45 marker?

Is f/45 actually likely to be where the pointer can end up?

If #2 is true, does that mean all the apertures are proportionally
off?

Is this something I should be concerned about and be requesting
repair?



Note that tagged this as "large format" rather than MF, because the lens itself is typically used in LF cameras.

Does the aperture ring "click" from one setting to the next? Or is it continuously variable?

@MichaelC It moves smoothly and is continuously variable.

The fact that you can continue past f/45 seems weird to me.  That being said, open the back and likely you can find a way to place a small flashlight so that it is aimed back at the lens from approximately at the position of the film plane. If achieved, the light will exit the lens backwards as parallel rays. Now mount a piece of paper over the lens as if it were an optical filter. You will see a circle of light projected on the paper. You can mark the diameter of this circle and measure it. This is the diameter of the entrance pupil. Make your measurement in millimeters. Set the aperture on each engraved setting and make a list of the corresponding diameters you measure. Divide each into the focal length which is 180mm. Your answers will be a close approximate of the actual f-numbers. Not exact because but close enough. Except for the first (widest) which is not a full stop, the sequence will be 5.6 -- 8 -- 11 -- 16 -- 22 -- 45 -- 64 -- 90 -- 126. Each value multiplied by 1.4.

It's weird to me as well. I will measure the aperture later, but today I'm going to run film through it for etc first time.  I'll also be bracketing a little, so I'll get a sense of how things compare to my light meter (which pragmatically is probably more important)
